# Splitting a line in CSV to two columns

Tags: awk, sed, grep, csv

I have a CSV where each line is like below

```
**./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties** **app.pass**
```

I want to use space as the seperator and get two seperate columns in the CSV like below

```
                                  PATH                   VALUE
    **./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties**   **app.pass**
```

Comment: Your question shows a space-separated file with 2 columns, you say it's a CSV but there's no comma in sight, then you show the desired output to be a space-separated file with 2 columns and no commas which you again say is a CSV. Hence all the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively just replacing space with a comma then?
With sed:

```
sed 's/ /,/g' file.csv
```

Comment: Brilliant!! It worked thanks a lot. btw, I have one more query now... if I have spaces in the path itself and I want the columns to be created just like it was above... Can you please help me with this? ./ABC/dce/app/config file list/fgh/pqr/app.properties app.pass

Comment: So to replace just the LAST space in each line: cat file.csv | sed 's/\\(.*\\) /\1,/'

Comment: @light [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged. If you have one more query then ask one more question.

Comment: `tr ' ' ','` (which is what that sed command does) is the job that `tr` exists to do.